# How to change the height of the banner to fit an image iOS UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, aspect-ratio

I have a banner view that shows 3 images. The image is currently cropped so that it would fit in the bannerView. I tried changing the content mpde of the imageView, but none of it works. I tried finding the aspect ratio based on the height and width of the image and then changing the height of the cell. But none of it seems to be working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wroing. I need to fit the image on the cell and need to change the height of the cell based on the aspect ratio of the width and height of the image.

Snippet of the code:

HomeViewController where the height is calculated:

```
extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let uiComponent = homeLayout[indexPath.section]
        switch uiComponent.type {
        case "banner":
            return ThemeLayoutProvider.homeBannerSize.height + 10
    }
}


struct ThemeLayoutProvider {
    static var bannerHeightRatio: CGFloat = 0.6
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

static var homeBannerSize: CGSize {
        return ThemeLayoutProvider.getHorizontallyAlignedCellSize(visibleCells: 1,
                                                                  horizontalPadding: 0,
                                                                  verticalPadding: 0,
                                                                  cellAspectRatio: ThemeLayoutProvider.bannerHeightRatio)
}
}

fileprivate static func getHorizontallyAlignedCellSize(visibleCells: CGFloat,
                                                           horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 0,
                                                           verticalPadding: CGFloat = 0,
                                                           cellAspectRatio: CGFloat = 0) -> CGSize {
        let cellWidth = (SCREEN_WIDTH/visibleCells) - (horizontalPadding*2)
        let cellHeight = (cellWidth * cellAspectRatio) - (verticalPadding*2)
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }
```

Banners Cell where the image is accessed:

```
extension Banners: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return componentLayout?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BannerCell", for: indexPath) as! BannerCell
        cell.bannerStyle = bannerStyle
        let anElement = componentLayout!.elements![indexPath.row]
        cell.bannerView.setImageFrom(URL.init(string: anElement.imageUrl ?? ""), placeholder: .imagePlaceHolderRect)
        return cell
    }
    }
```

Is there anyway to change the height of the cell based on width : height ration as 2:1 or something that would make the image fit in the screen?

Comment: Most ideal way to create a view (banner in your case), that can resize according to the containing UIImageView would be to ensure UIView has X,Y and WIDTH properties so that height will be calculated dynamically. For ex giving your view only top, leading and trailing constraints from its superview.

Comment: @KishanSadhwani Hello. Sorry, I'm very new to UIKit. Can you explain it to me in detail?